# Notepad++ Open all documents that are search term available

Tags: regex, notepad++

How can I open all documents that are search term in notepad++?

**Eg**: I am searching in folder called "`products`" for "Thank you for subscribe" word to replace with "`We will get back to you shortly`" and I found **120** results from **60** pages. I cannot blindly replace all while I want to check and replace...

So, I want to open all 60 documents in Notepad++ at once instead of clicking on individual and checking...

Is there any shortcut for the same please?

Comment: right click anyone of the search result and press open all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeaah.... I found the answer.

Just `Ctrl + A` or select all from Results window, then right click and click on "**Open all**"